# RawOptionsSetType raises error in Swift in Xcode6

Tags: swift, enums, xcode6

According to [this article](http://nshipster.com/rawoptionsettype/) from NSHipster, I wanted to use the following approach to create an enum that allows bitmask:

```
struct Toppings : RawOptionSetType, BooleanType {
    private var value: UInt = 0

    init(_ value: UInt) {
        self.value = value
    }

    // MARK: RawOptionSetType

    static func fromMask(raw: UInt) -> Toppings {
        return self(raw)
    }

    // MARK: RawRepresentable

    static func fromRaw(raw: UInt) -> Toppings? {
        return self(raw)
    }

    func toRaw() -> UInt {
        return value
    }

    // MARK: BooleanType

    var boolValue: Bool {
        return value != 0
    }


    // MARK: BitwiseOperationsType

    static var allZeros: Toppings {
        return self(0)
    }

    // MARK: NilLiteralConvertible

    static func convertFromNilLiteral() -> Toppings {
        return self(0)
    }

    // MARK: -

    static var None: Toppings           { return self(0b0000) }
    static var ExtraCheese: Toppings    { return self(0b0001) }
    static var Pepperoni: Toppings      { return self(0b0010) }
    static var GreenPepper: Toppings    { return self(0b0100) }
    static var Pineapple: Toppings      { return self(0b1000) } }
```

It raised four following errors:

```
Initializer 'init' has different argument names from those required by protocol 'RawRepresentable' ('init(rawValue:)')
Type 'Toppings' does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'
Type 'Toppings' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
Type 'Toppings' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'
```

I managed to satisfy `Equatable` error by implementing `func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool`. But it seems to fail to recognize this function.

Is there a solution to solve all the errors above? I prefer this solution over the `toRaw()` one. So I am highly interested in if there can be a fix to the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To conform `NilLiteralConvertible` add another initializer and init your struct to its `nil` value:

```
init(nilLiteral: ()) { }
```

To conform `RawRepresentable`:

```
typealias RawValue = UInt

var rawValue: RawValue {
    get {
        return value
    }
}

init(rawValue value: UInt) {
    self.value = value
}
```

When you need to find out how to conform to a specific protocol, in Xcode, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> on the protocol name.